# Minecraft 1.7.2 setting textures efficiently

Tags: java, textures, minecraft

I set textures in each individual file, this is the non efficient way to set it

```
this.setUnlocalizedName("ItemName");
this.setTextureName("MyModName:ItemName");
```

This way made sense to me, but didn't work:

```
this.setUnlocalizedName("ItemName");
this.setTextureName(OtherClassName.MODID + ":" + this.getUnlocalizedName());
```

the 'OtherClassName.MODID' is referring to a variable in another class that contains 'MyModName'
The this.getUnlocalizedName() gets the UnlocalizedName that has been declared, 'ItemName'

Any help? I am not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getUnlocalizedName` is slightly weird - it returns the string you passed into `setUnlocalizedName`, but with "item." at the start. The joys of working with deobfuscated code...

This would work:

```
String name = "ItemName";
this.setUnlocalizedName(name);
this.setTextureName(OtherClassName.MODID + ":" + name);
```

Note that it's not more efficient as in faster to run, but it might be faster to write if you change the item name a lot.

Comment: could I not '.substring(5)' after to remove the '.item'?                 EDIT: the '.substring(5) doesn't work like it should. hmmm'

Comment: It doesn't work, I have  this.setUnlocalizedName("CobblestoneMixture"); 
this.setTextureName(MoreEquipment.MODID + this.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));'

Comment: Aahhhhh Thank You! I knew I would miss something like that lol

Comment: To make it even more efficient, I made another class with a method for it:                                                                     public class SetTexture { public SetTexture(Item ItemName) { ItemName.setTextureName(MoreEquipment.MODID + ":" + ItemName.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5)}}                             It will work, but the parameter passing isn't working, I know I need to pass the 'ItemName' but i'm not sure how to pass it

Comment: Now I have: 
`public class SetTextureClass {                                                                                                     
 public static void SetTexture(Item ItemName) {  
      ItemName.setTextureName(MoreEquipment.MODID + ":" + ItemName.getUnlocalizedName().substring(5));
 }
}`
and to call it I use this: `SetTextureClass.SetTexture(MoreEquipment.CobblestoneMixture);`
SetTextureClass is the class the method is in.                   There are no errors, but the game crashes upon loading.
Help???

Comment: Stack Overflow is supposed to have one problem per question.